# Can I use environment variables in paths to crates in `Cargo.toml`?

Tags: windows, rust, rust-cargo

Is it possible to use environment variables in a `Cargo.toml` file?

Like so:

```ini
[package]
name = "tmp-xzxgxn"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
# bevy = {branch = "main", git = "https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy.git"}
# bevy = { path = "~/Documents/GitHub/bevy" }
bevy = { path = "%USERPROFILE%/Documents/GitHub/bevy" }
```

Note that `~` doesn't work either.